# Java generics - accept float and int

Tags: java, generics

How can I program my class to accept both Integers and Floats, I suppose I'll need to use generics, am I correct?

```
public class Vec2 {

private int x, y;

public Vec2(int xa, int ya) {
    this.x = xa;
    this.y = ya;
}
public Vec2() {
    this(0, 0);
}
public Vec2(Vec2 vec) {
    this(vec.x, vec.y);
}

public void addX(int xa) {
    x+=xa; // I get an exception here when I try to use generics.
}
public void addY(int ya) {
    y+=ya; // I get an exception here when I try to use generics.
}
```

Any ideas how to program my class to accept floats, integers and doubles altogether?

Comment: ONLY floats, integers, and doubles? Just make three different implementations of a `Vec`, `VecFloat`, `VecInt`, etc..

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Making 3 classes is just a headache, that would be more flexible to make just one class..and I am interested in studying generics anyhow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26851492/arithmetic-with-generic-numbers/26851603#26851603

Answer (score 1):

For the time being, we cannot have generics over primitives like `int` or `double`, so you will be forced to use boxed representations.  It really is easier to just make a separate class for `int` and `double`.  But if you want to use generics, here's how you can do it in a type-safe way (using java8):

```
public class Vec2<T> {

    private final BinaryOperator<T> adder;

    private T x, y;

    private Vec2(BinaryOperator<T> adder, T x, T y) {
        this.adder = adder;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void addX(T xa) {
        x = adder.apply(x, xa);
    }

    public void addY(T ya) {
        y = adder.apply(y, ya);
    }

    public static Vec2<Integer> ofInt(Integer x, Integer y) {
        return new Vec2<>(Integer::sum, x, y);
    }

    public static Vec2<Double> ofDouble(Double x, Double y) {
        return new Vec2<>(Double::sum, x, y);
    }
}
```

---

```
Vec2<Integer> intvec = Vec2.ofInt(5, 3);
intvec.addX(8);

Vec2<Double> dblvec = Vec2.ofDouble(5.2, 8.9);
dblvec.addY(-.9);
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't, merely have your class inherit from [Number](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html) and use type checking to ensure that values are of the appropriate class, if necessary, e.g.

```
Class IsraelG99sClass {
    Number n;

    public Number add(Number n2) {
        if (n instanceof Integer && n2 instanceof Integer) {
             return new Integer(n.intValue() + n2.intValue());
        } else { 
             return new Double(n.doubleValue() + n2.doubleValue());
        }
    }

    public Number getValue() {
        if ((n instanceof Integer) || (n instanceof Float)) {
              return n;
        } // handle the other case as appropriate
   }
}
```

Comment: I am yet to understand how I would be able to add 2 numbers together using this idea, any ideas?

Comment: I've put a sample of how an add operation should be implemented

Answer (score 0):

You could use `BigDecimal` to back your `Vec2` and then you could use create `addX` and `addY` method(s) for `long` and `double` fairly easily. Something like,

```
public class Vec2 {
    private BigDecimal x, y;

    public Vec2(double xa, double ya) {
        this.x = BigDecimal.valueOf(xa);
        this.y = BigDecimal.valueOf(ya);
    }

    public Vec2(long xa, long ya) {
        this.x = BigDecimal.valueOf(xa);
        this.y = BigDecimal.valueOf(ya);
    }

    public Vec2(Vec2 vec) {
        this.x = vec.x;
        this.y = vec.y;
    }

    public void addX(double xa) {
        x = x.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(xa));
    }

    public void addX(long xa) {
        x = x.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(xa));
    }

    public void addY(double ya) {
        y = y.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(ya));
    }

    public void addY(long ya) {
        y = y.add(BigDecimal.valueOf(ya));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("x = %s, y = %s", x.toString(), y.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, but BigDecimals are notorious memory hogs, and his question was about how to apply generics.

Comment: @MichaelEricOberlin OP did include *Any ideas how to program my class to accept floats, integers and doubles altogether?* Only type that can do that is `BigDecimal`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I liked the idea, not sure if I am going to use it, but the man who downvoted your answer totally got it all wrong, I will up vote it. Thank you.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Number will also let you do so.

Answer (score -1):

Floats and ints are very different values with vastly different mins and maxes. I would try using doubles as the data member with overloaded constructors for different variable types instead of generics unless generics are really needed.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use generics and make your x and y attributes of type T.

But you won't be able to just implement the addX and addY in they way you want.

Check these other answers on how to implement a generic number addition, it's not as simple but you should be able to do it that way.

[Java Generics and adding numbers together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8669838/java-generics-and-adding-numbers-together)

[how to write a generic method for adding numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037970/how-to-write-a-generic-method-for-adding-numbers)

Comment: The gist of your answer is in the duplicates you linked. Extract the relevant information there into your answer.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, I'm operating under the assumption that you want x and y to be of varying (generic) type.

For this, you would want:

```
public class Vec2<E extends Number> {

private E x, y;

public Vec2(E xa, E ya) {
    this.x = xa;
    this.y = ya;
}

//Not _easily_ possible with generics, as the compiler has no guarantee that
//zero is an acceptable value. Consider some variation of a Factory pattern,
//but this will work. Note that there is an "officially"-unchecked cast warning.
public Vec2() {
    super();

    final Number zero = 0.0; 
    this.x = (E)zero;
    this.y = (E)zero;
}

public Vec2(Vec2<E> vec) {
    this(vec.x, vec.y);
}

public void addX(E xa) {
    Number c = x.doubleValue() + xa.doubleValue();
    x = (E)c;
}

public void addY(E ya) {
    Number c = y.doubleValue() + ya.doubleValue();
    x = (E)c;
}
```

This should work well. While I encourage you to use generics, note that keeping a numeric type (like int, float, or double) as a generic is often not advisable, as they're only similar on the surface. When you dig into the operations of, say, "+", they are radically different dependent on type. You will also have an assortment of unchecked-cast warnings in this code; perhaps I could have rooted them out properly had I the time, but this just goes back to my warning about generic numbers.

You will also notice a few flukes of the language doing this, such as the way that `(E)zero` works, but (E)(0.0) does not.

By and large, though, generics are a much easier and cleaner way to go about things than inheritance, when it is possible.

Comment: This will break as soon as you try to expose `x` or `y` as `E`.

Comment: How would it break? E is the declared generic type.  Just use `public E getX()`; from the outside it will be the generic.

Comment: If you declare a `Vec2<Integer> vec;` and use `vec.getX()`, you'd be expecting an `Integer`, but you'd get back a `Double`, assuming that you had previously used your `addX`. That will cause a `ClassCastException`.

Comment: Ah, good call. I suppose the other option would be to select a method based on the class of the parameter; but this is really one more reason why I recommend against using generics for numbers.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Yep, just figured it out, well I'll go with using double instead of using generics, seems more safe and flexible at the moment.